# Get parent storage account for given container

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I have a bookmark to given container inside Azure Storage Account. When I click on the bookmark in Chrome, I get to the container alright, but I do not know how to "click" my way to the parent storage account. This is how it looks like in browser:
[image]

**How do I get to the parent Storage Account from here?**

My link looks like this:
[https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Storage/ContainerMenuBlade/~/overview/storageAccountId/%2Fsubscriptions%2F[[subscription-id-here]]%2FresourceGroups%2F[[rg-here]]%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Storage%2FstorageAccounts%2F[[storage-account-here]]/path/[[rest-of-path]]](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Storage/ContainerMenuBlade/%7E/overview/storageAccountId/%2Fsubscriptions%2F%5B%5Bsubscription-id-here%5D%5D%2FresourceGroups%2F%5B%5Brg-here%5D%5D%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Storage%2FstorageAccounts%2F%5B%5Bstorage-account-here%5D%5D/path/%5B%5Brest-of-path%5D%5D)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the URL you’re using. Do remove any sensitive information from the URL before sharing.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri done

Answer (score 1):

> **Get parent storage account for given container**

In the below GIF, When I click on the **`bookmark`** in the browser, same as it directly goes to the container page.

When you need to get the parent storage account you need to click any file in your container with properties.

[image]

Once, you get the storage account name copied and paste it home you can get the parent storage account.

[image]

Comment: not bad. Kinda weird, and I think Microsoft should make it easier... but thats the only thing We have rn.